# Change default direction for rotation

Tags: android, rotation

I want to rotate an image from left to right and right to left direction.
I am using the following code to rotate the image.`matrix.postRotate(90);

```
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap_rotate, 0, 0,
                bitmap_rotate.getWidth(), bitmap_rotate.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);`
```

But it always rotate image in same direction.I want to change the direction of rotation.Is there any way to change the direction.I have googled a lot but not find the right one.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rotate by 360 - yourAngle.

In your case :
`matrix.postRotate(270);`